# Silverlight XAML file error: The member "Margin" is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I have a reference to a silverlight xaml file in my project. When i try to build this project it throws following error

```
The member "Margin" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DBServer.Selenium.Silvernium.ReferenceApplication.SilverlightFixture"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
<navigation:Frame x:Name="frameContent" Source="/MainPage.xaml" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem too. maybe you can remove the navigation control, complie the solution. and then add it again, compile it. i guess other errors makes the error of margin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the frame inside a grid?

```
<Grid>
<navigation:Frame x:Name="frameContent" Source="/MainPage.xaml" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

because you are saying Margin="0,0,0,0" but in the XAML you don't have any other content as reference to the that distance defined in the Margin,so try or by removing the Margin or putting inside a grid